# C# multiple contentpresenter on a button style (windows 8.1)

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, contentpresenter

I'm trying to display 2 data on a button, using custom style.

So, I wrote an XAML code like below, with one 'ContentPresenter.'

```
<Style x:Key="Num_of_Comments" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" x:Name="RootGrid">
                        <Grid 
                            Height="42" 
                            Width="42">
                            <Ellipse
                                x:Name="Ellipse"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                StrokeThickness="2"
                                UseLayoutRounding="False" />
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="21"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="21"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter 
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And I use this style like this.

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Comments}" Style="{StaticResource Num_of_Comments}" IsEnabled="False" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{Binding Comments_color}"/>
```

Then, this button looks like this

[Original button](http://cfile10.uf.tistory.com/image/2462E54F538E95FD069BD9)

Anyway, I'd like to add one more 'ContentPresenter' in the style, and display one more different data on the button.

But if I add one more 'ContentPresenter' into the style, I don't know how to assign 2 different data on each 'ContentPresenter.'

This is the button what I want to make.

[The button I want to make](http://cfile28.uf.tistory.com/image/26730D4F538E95FC332A33)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Tag` property on button to assign additional data and bind the second `ContentPresenter` `Content` as follows:

```
   <ContentPresenter 
       Grid.Row="1"
       Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center">
   </ContentPresenter>
```

and on `Button`:

```
 <Button Tag="{Binding OTHERDATAPROPERTY}" Content="{Binding Comments}"></Button>
```